# Join Node or Merge Node?

Tags: uml, diagram, activity-diagram

I am trying to make an activity diagram of a user for my system and I am unsure if the flow should come down to a Join Node or Merge Node before the user can log off. Here is the one I have made sa of now. Could anyone explain to me what's the difference?

[image: Join Node]

Comment: According to your design I can only do one thing on your system and then I **must** log out. I'm guessing that is not how ou meant it?

Comment: Ah, yes. So I reckon I should go for Merge Node instead? @GeertBellekens

Comment: A merge node won't help if you don't allow the user to do something else after his first action. Currently the only thing they can do after doing one of the action is "Logout"

Comment: @GeertBellekens Is it better if after the homepage, I added a Fork Node to split the flow into multiple concurrent flows like build itinerary etc. Then join all of them again with a Join Node that has one outgoing flow to a decision node named 'Go Back To Homepage'. If yes, the flow goes back to the homepage action state and if no, it goes to a new 'continue action' action node.

Comment: Is that how you user a system? I personally can only do one task at a time, not all of them in parallel. Besides if you split them using a fork, and then join them, you are basically saying that the user **has** to do all of them. And it seems reasonable that I can logout from your system without doing anyhting as well. In that case Logout should be at the same level as the other actions a user can do.

Comment: Ohhh. Right, interesting! I should probably remove the fork node and just direct the action flows from homepage to the rest. Then instead of using a join node, I think I should add a decision node that gives them the option of continuing their thing or going back to homepage.

Comment: Yes, and also "Homepage" is a bad name for an Action. It doesn't "Do" anything

Comment: @GeertBellekens Alright, I think I got a gist of it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a join (though I first remembered wrongly and thanks to [@AxelScheithauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9430250/axel-scheithauer) pointing out my error). P. 401 of UML 2.5

> **15.5.3.1 Executable Nodes**
>
> ...
>
> When an ExecutableNode completes an execution, the control token representing that execution is removed from the ExecutableNode and control tokens are offered on all outgoing ControlFlows of the ExecutableNode. That is, there is an implicit fork of the flow of control from the ExecutableNode to its outgoing ControlFlows.

That means that all 6 actions below will start in parallel which does not mean they must run concurrently. But all of them need completion in order to continue after the join below. (I doubt that this is desired.)

There's a (double) 2nd flaw in the top decision back-flows. They need to go back to the top merge. Otherwise neither Login nor Register would start since they expect 3 or 2 tokens where only one would arrive.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much! As for the homepage, must a guard be specified? I thought it was usually for decision nodes mostly. And could you clarify more on the mistake about the 2nd flaw?

Comment: You can have an action emit more than one control flows. Only one will send a token. So a guard will control which one that would be. Without it's (per sepcification) random.

Comment: Would adding a fork node help? After the homepage, adding a Fork Node to split the flow into multiple concurrent flows like build itinerary, search for destination etc.

Comment: Sorry, but in UML 2 multiple outgoing control flows _are_ an implicit fork. Therefore, a join node is the correct element, if you want to wait for all six actions to have completed before logging out. They don't need to _start_ at the same time. The fork only says they are _enabled_ at the same time. If you are a djinn, you can work on them in parallel. If not, you can do them in any order. Of course, if you want to describe a typical user, she would only do them one at a time but potentially multiple times. Therefore you probably should use a decision node and loop back to it.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer Oh, I found it... 15.5.3.1. My memory is getting worse :-(